# JS displays HTML instead of the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my input

```
 <input type="text" class="ChampionInput" list="champions" name="champion[]"`placeholder="Champion" required>
```

And here is my js

```
document.forms["first_form_champions"].oninput = function(e) {
  var champion = this["champion[]"];
  console.log(champion);
};
```

I'm trying to display in console.log(champion) value of that input

Comment: You are referencing the element, so you get the element when you log it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/38/)**

You have to add `.value` :

```
this["champion[]"].value;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried that earlier and I get an error this.champion[].val is not a function

Comment: jQuery solution is WRONG. That is a DOM element you are referencing, not a jQuery object.